# Julia: where is the missing end?

Tags: julia, syntax-error

I am trying to convert a program written in Python to Julia. I have been using Julia for the last 2 hours.

My code is the following:

```
function spin_add(buff,clust,spins,padd)
    if size(buff) == 0
        return(clust)
    else
        i = buff[1][1] #row
        j = buff[1][2]] #column
        L = size(spins[1:1,:])
        u = i-1
        d = i+1
        r = j+1
        l = j-1
        if i == L
            d = 1
        end
        if i == 1
            u = L
        end
        if j == L
            r = 0
        end
        if j == 1
            l = L
        end
        nei = [(u,j),(d,j),(i,r),(i,l)]
        popfirst!(buff)
        for site in nei
            if site not in clust
                if spins[site] == spins[i,j]
                    if rand() < padd
                        push(clust,site)
                        push(buff,site)
                    end
                end
            end
        end     
        return(spin_add(buff, clust, spins, padd))
    end
end
```

However, I am getting an error that says that an `end` is not added. The exact error is

```
syntax: "if" at In[10]:2 expected "end", got "]"

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[10]:6
 [2] eval
   @ .\boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:1116
```

I do not understand where I must add the `end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
j = buff[1][2]-->]<-- #column
```

Taking out that extra "]" should solve it.